# UISearchBar in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to add a search function to my tableview. I've started by creating the UITableView, which works perfect. The problem is when I start writing in the search bar I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x8c44c00> valueForUndefinedKey:]:
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
```

Then i've added the searchbar and searchdisplay to the viewcontroller.

searchdisplaycontroller outlets:

[image]

viewcontroller outlets:

[image]

in viewdidload

```
self.filteredArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[finalArray count]];
```

numberOfRows method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        NSLog(@"lol");
        return [filteredArray count];
    } else {
        return [rows count];
    }

}
```

rest of the methods:

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    // Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
    // Remove all objects from the filtered search array
    [self.filteredArray removeAllObjects];
    // Filter the array using NSPredicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@",searchText];
    filteredArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[finalArray     filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    // Tells the table data source to reload when text changes
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller     shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
    // Tells the table data source to reload when scope bar selection changes
    [self filterContentForSearchText:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Helped you to put your screen shots into your questions. and voted you up for giving you 5 reputations, so you can add image next time.

Comment: Thank you! i know the link was not optimal, but was the only solution i could find.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your predicate. If you see in the error message, it says `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'`

In your predicate,

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@",searchText];
```

you're searching for the text on a property that doesn't exist (`name`). Without seeing more of your code or knowing more of what you're trying to accomplish, changing the predicate to say `@"SELF contains..."` instead of `@"SELF.name contains..."` should do the trick.

You can see [the Apple docs on predicates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798-SW1) or [this article](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/10/19/searching-arrays-with-nspredicate-and-blocks.html) for more information.